# DSharpPlus edit channel topic

Tags: c#, dsharp+

I'm trying to edit a text channel's topic. I tried using `DiscordChannel.ModifyAsync` but I have no idea what an `Action<ChannelEditModel>` is. How can I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Lambda expression:

```
    public async Task ModifyChannel(CommandContext ctx, ulong id, [RemainingText] string topic)
    {
        var chn = await ctx.Client.GetChannelAsync(id);
        Action<ChannelEditModel> action = new(x => x.Topic = topic);
        await chn.ModifyAsync(action);

    }
```